# NSLocalizedString not working for some word

Tags: ios, localizable.strings

I have english, Japanese, korea Localizable.strings file. I cannot load some word from korea file. I have checked spelling, capital letter or small letter also. It is correct. I have cleaned project, reset simulator and delete app on device also. It is not working for some words. May I know how to do?

Comment: Could you please show that words.

Comment: My app has support for 10 languages, including Korean, Chinese and Japanese, and we never had this kind of problem. Could you show your Localizable.strings file and the code where you are calling this specific word?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A common problem is this: If there is an error in your localisable.strings file, anything after that error will be just ignored. The line that you are checking may be fine; if the line 10 lines above is broken, it won't work. If that is the problem, for example the item in the next line isn't going to work either.

Cleaning project, reset simulator, delete app on device, are all not going to do anything for you.

Comment: It is soooo bad. I have commented out all and check only that word. It is okay. Is there any easy way to detect which is broken?

Comment: In my case, I had tried to add a comment to localizable.strings file as `#comment` and all the translations after that comment was not working (I don't know why I added that line in the first place). I changed it to `//comment` and it worked.

Comment: Thank you very much. after spending 2 days to find the reason. xCode not presenting warning during build.

Answer (score 1):

Also it may be some words, that repeats. If two same keys in Localizable.strings - it may be work not properly.

Also i found, that `continue` key make some bugs, so i changed it to `CONTINUE`.
HINT something like `continue_question` and anything that contains `continue` - makes same bug.

It seems like there are another words like this. Also got to say, that i didn't delete app and clean build folder due to debag this. In Xcode 7.3 it was't necessary.

Comment: In my case all other cases did not work at all. And complier does not show any warning/error in Localizable.strings file. Then I have started my key value format as **"key" = "value";**
And I found some my stupid mistake which was in format that was **"key"; = "value";** Note : there was a extra semicolon (*) after key . After removed that I localisation works like a charm. Very easy way to catch your format. Just comment entire file's key value pairs. Then just put a key value and run the code. I think you will get know what is the actual issue. Thanks Guys.

Answer (score 0):

It might also be due to a blank space in one of your empty lines in the `Localizable.strings` file.

It's tough to spot but you can spot it by looking at which point of the file the strings start to fail localization.

Answer (score -1):

Check or search for # in your localizable.String  .if there is any remove it . the key value pairs below the # are not working